# Fetch all docs in a chunk which is ranged by a hashed shard key

Tags: mongodb

shard key ranged chunk1:

```
{ "username" : 1 } -->> { "username" : 5 } on : testmongo52 Timestamp(677, 48)
```

Hashed shard key ranged chunk2:

```
{ "username" : NumberLong("-7758233114527756159") } -->> { "username" : NumberLong("-6294187730596495985") } on : testmongo51 Timestamp(8, 9)
```

When getting all documents from chunk1, I can use a mongo shell method:

```
db.club.find({"username":{"$gte":1,"$lt":5}})
```

How can I do that from chunk2?

I don't think "_hashBsonElement" is an efficient way to realize that.

Comment: Why the heck would you want to do that? Simply remove the shard from the cluster and let the balancer do the rest.

Comment: The balancer just has normal insert speed while it is migrating chunks.Too slow to extend.So my metor told me to improve them,The range indexes sharding based tool works well which alomost achive the batch insert speed limitation. But hash indexes sharding one takes too long in the Finding phase.

Comment: Still fail to see the point. Data consistency will be a ***huge*** problem in case the operation aborts for whatever reason. Data might be changed on the old or the new shard in between. To make this *safe*, you have to reinvent the wheel. The easiest and safest way to achieve what you want is to disable the balancer and use the [`moveChunk` database command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/moveChunk/#dbcmd.moveChunk) for each chunk on the shard to be removed. What basically is what happens when you remove a shard.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. First of all, I need muti-threads to move chunks .And I am being able to handle a consistency problem by some way. The point is that faster and faster.If you check out the mongoDB balancer changelogs you will find most of the time is spending at clone phase.And it is too slow. e.g. 64MB chunk takse almost 12 minutes to migrate. But after improvement,20 Seconds is enough.Imagine that a batch of new servers join to the cluster.,why don't  migrate as fast as possible to distribute your data?It also makes sense if you want to delete one of your loaded shards.

Comment: I don't know your sample size, but that doesn't sound right. The exact reason why the default chunk size is 64MB (and chunks get migrated at around *half* of that size) is because a chunk migration is supposed to be fast. I have *never* even seen something close to that. 12 minutes for a chunk? There is something seriously wrong with your cluster. My bet is that there is either a problem with the shard key, the network or the IOPS (or a combination with both).

Comment: I do that because my mentor told me it is still not fast enough when adding a new shard to cluster, I felt the purpose he want me to achieve is as fast  as possible to migrate chunks from an overloaded shard to the new one.Anyway mongoDB balancer indeed limit the insert speed while migrating a chunk.

Comment: I am trying to create an B+ tree outside to store the hashed value(as keyword) pointing to  shard key value(as pointed value). I don't know if I can succeed,but I have to give a shot or I am wasting 2 months on this thing

Comment: Imho, the time is already wasted. During management of a cluster, you need to have certain thresholds defined in your monitoring. For example, I usually have an alert when the disk IOPs reach 80% (up to 90% in some cases) of the disks' maximum capacity. If the alert turns out to not be caused by an exceptional spike, I add another shard. This happens long before you run into problems, but late enough to be efficient. No need to speed up the chunk migration and risk a performance impact due to fiddling with the process.